# This mod which I'm trying to compile is having a lot of error CS0246. More than a 1000 of them. I tried downloading a bunch of things and it didntwork

Tags: c#

https://github.com/tukasa0001/TownOfHost
Im trying to compile this mod, but Im getting a lot of errors.

This is the error:  error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AmongUs' could not be
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

There are more than 1000 of these errors. These are some of the many errors which are in the main.cs file.

```
using AmongUs.GameOptions;
using BepInEx;
using BepInEx.Configuration;
using BepInEx.IL2CPP;
using HarmonyLib;
using UnhollowerRuntimeLib;
using UnityEngine;
```

All of the above is error CS0246. The code on github is a mod that is being used by many people and it shouldnt be outdated or anything. Any ideas on how to get this fixed?

I have dotnet version 7.0.102 and visual studio 2022

I thought the issue might be with visual studios so I used cmd to try and build the code but its the same thing with 1377 errors. I also installed something called nuget from visual studios but it didnt fix it.

I tried copying among us game files into the same folder as the code but it didnt work as well. Normally after compiling you do this and run the game and the mod will work, but here I obviously dont have the compiled files. Btw I know the user already put the compiled files on github. I want to edit some texts that appear in game which can only be changed from the code it seems.

Comment: from the csproj I read `<Reference Include="$(AmongUs)\BepInEx\core\*.dll" />`. which means you need that assembly located on that folder

Comment: Where do I get that assembly?

Comment: ask the repos owner. No idea, honestly.